# How to highlight element in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to highlight (around the border) element that is found in selenium webdriver using C#. I have search the net all i found was java codes, but need it in C#.

or is there any other way to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no native way to do this, but because Selenium allows you use to execute Javascript, you can accomplish it just with a little more work:

Therefore the question becomes "how do I change an elements borders in Javascript?"

If you use jQuery it's a little bit easier, you could find the element and then set some border properties. jQuery has a neat little `css` property that allows you to pass in a `JSON` dictionary of values, it will handle setting them all for you, an example would be like:

```
jQuery('div.tagged > a:first').css({ "border-width" : "2px", "border-style" : "solid", "border-color" : "red" });
```

That would find an element, and set it's border to be `solid` at `2px` wide with a border colour of `red`.

However, if you already have an `IWebElement` instance of the element (likely) you can take the 'finding' responsibility out of jQuery/Javascript and make it simpler again.

This would be executed something like:

```
var jsDriver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var element = // some element you find;
string highlightJavascript = @"$(arguments[0]).css({ ""border-width"" : ""2px"", ""border-style"" : ""solid"", ""border-color"" : ""red"" });";
jsDriver.ExecuteScript(highlightJavascript, new object[] { element });
```

If you just want basic Javascript, then you could make use of the `.cssText` property, which allows you to give a full string of CSS styles instead of adding them individually (although I don't know how supported it is cross browser):

```
var jsDriver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var element = // some element you find;
string highlightJavascript = @"arguments[0].style.cssText = ""border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: red"";";
jsDriver.ExecuteScript(highlightJavascript, new object[] { element });
```

**(Although there are more ways, I've just gone for the most verbose to make it clearer)**

Answer (score 5):

C# Extension Method: Highlights and Clears in 3 seconds.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

public static class SeleniumUtil
{
   public static void Highlight(this  IWebElement context)
    {
        var rc = (RemoteWebElement)context;
        var driver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)rc.WrappedDriver;
        var script = @"arguments[0].style.cssText = ""border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: red""; ";
        driver.ExecuteScript(script, rc);
        Observable.Timer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3)).Subscribe(p =>
        {
            var clear = @"arguments[0].style.cssText = ""border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: red""; ";
            driver.ExecuteScript(clear, rc);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Arran i just modified your answer..

```
var jsDriver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var element = //element to be found
string highlightJavascript = @"arguments[0].style.cssText = ""border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: red"";";
jsDriver.ExecuteScript(highlightJavascript, new object[] { element });
```

it works perfectly... 
thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Write below JavaScript Executor code in your Class file

```
public void elementHighlight(WebElement element) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript(
                        "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                        element, "color: red; border: 5px solid red;");
                js.executeScript(`enter code here`
                        "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                        element, "");
            }
```

Call the above method from Selenium test case to highlight a web page element. Check out below code which shows how it is done. elementHighlight method is called with searchBox as an argument.

```
@Test
    public void GoogleSearch() throws Exception, SQLException {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//center/div[2]")).click();
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/input"));
        elementHighlight(searchBox);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/input")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/input")).sendKeys("Test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button")).click();

    }
```

On executing the above test, Selenium test will highlight the search box on Google home page. You can reuse elementHighlight method for highlighting any elements on web page.